# How do I install mbstring with PHP on CentOS 6.2

Tags: php, centos, installation

I install yum install php55w 
I try

```
# yum install php-mbstring

Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.telepoint.bg
 * epel: mirrors.neterra.net
 * extras: mirror.telepoint.bg
 * updates: mirror.telepoint.bg
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.3.3-40.el6_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6 for package: php-mbstring-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-40.el6_6 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php55w-common-5.5.21-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php55w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

every time I get this error, no matter what I do.

How this can be resolved

Answer (score 2):

Did you try installing php55-mbstring? So:

`yum install php55-mbstring`

Comment: No package php55-mbstring available

Comment: what about php55w-mbstring ?